# Using Zurb Foundation and Symfony2

Tags: javascript, css, symfony, zurb-foundation, assetic

In my Symfony2 application, I am using the Zurb Foundation to built my layout on.
This keeps giving me headaches... the css works pretty well but the js often does not work. The files are loaded and no errors are reported (Zurb does its job just fine), but for instance when clicking on tabs nothing happens.

I expect to find the error in the loading of the foundation files through Assetic. I am not using any filters, but I need Assetic to load the files from app\resources\public. As this is a non-web folder, if I load these files directly I get "forbidden"-error.

Where do you guys put your global css and js files from Foundation, in your Symfony2 app? In a bundle or in the public folder like me? Do you have any advice on how to make this run smoothly?

**EDIT:** it seems that none of my Zurb Foundation js is working at all... however it has loaded without errors. Documentation on this seems very rare if existent at all.

Comment: Do you have a solution for Foundation5 with Comapss in Symfony2, please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075824/foundation5-with-compass-and-assetic-in-symfony2 ?

Answer (score 2):

'Loading order' was the answer... the js files were read in the wrong order and that caused the problems.

This is the solution:

When linking to your js libraries, make sure you mention each file individually so you can determine the order. Next, link to the app.js files *last*. If you don't, all files will be found and correctly loaded but they won't be used by the Zurb Foundation. If you look at the app.js file you will see it loads the libraries, and returns null for each library that is not found - at that particular moment in time.

So, instead of linking to your js files like this:

```
{% javascripts 
 '@UnknownblissZurbfoundationBundle/Resources/public/javascripts/*'
%}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Do it like this:

```
{% javascripts 
 '@UnknownblissZurbfoundationBundle/Resources/public/javascripts/jquery.placeholder.js'
 '@UnknownblissZurbfoundationBundle/Resources/public/javascripts/modernizr.foundation.js'
 '@UnknownblissZurbfoundationBundle/Resources/public/javascripts/foundation.min.js'
 '@UnknownblissZurbfoundationBundle/Resources/public/javascripts/jquery.foundation.accordion.js'
 '@UnknownblissZurbfoundationBundle/Resources/public/javascripts/jquery.foundation.alerts.js'
 '@UnknownblissZurbfoundationBundle/Resources/public/javascripts/jquery.foundation.buttons.js'
 '@UnknownblissZurbfoundationBundle/Resources/public/javascripts/jquery.foundation.forms.js'      '@UnknownblissZurbfoundationBundle/Resources/public/javascripts/jquery.foundation.mediaQueryToggle.js'
 '@UnknownblissZurbfoundationBundle/Resources/public/javascripts/jquery.foundation.navigation.js'
 '@UnknownblissZurbfoundationBundle/Resources/public/javascripts/jquery.foundation.topbar.js'
 '@UnknownblissZurbfoundationBundle/Resources/public/javascripts/jquery.foundation.reveal.js'
 '@UnknownblissZurbfoundationBundle/Resources/public/javascripts/jquery.foundation.tabs.js'
 '@UnknownblissZurbfoundationBundle/Resources/public/javascripts/jquery.foundation.tooltips.js'
 '@UnknownblissZurbfoundationBundle/Resources/public/javascripts/app.js'
 '@UnknownblissZurbfoundationBundle/Resources/public/javascripts/*'
 %}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

That way, *you* determine the loading order instead of Symfony2. Still it is a wise idea to end with a wildcard link, so anything that you might have forgotten will still be linked.

It might look like all added benefits of using Assetic are thrown away this way, but you still have the advantage of using the namespace and by using a filter you can have Assetic make these files into one. This will limit the amount of requests needed. So the only true downside is the extra code needed...

PS
The order chosen above worked fine for me, but you might want to come up with your own order.

Answer (score 2):

If you're still looking for a cleaner way, this guy was nice enough to make a bundle for Foundation as well as jQuery & Modernizr.

https://github.com/bmatzner/BmatznerFoundationBundle

This is all you need:

```
<head>
  //...
{% block stylesheets %}
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/bmatznerfoundation/css/foundation.min.css') }}" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet"/>
{% endblock %}
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/bmatznerjquery/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/bmatznerfoundation/js/foundation.min.js') }}"></script>
</head>
```