# Foundation5 with Compass and Assetic in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, zurb-foundation, bower, assetic, compass-sass

I want to config Foundation5 with Compass and Assetic in Symfony2, I have installed foundation as they say at http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html :

```
npm install -g bower grunt-cli
gem install foundation
```

In `config.yml` have configured in this way :

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        compass: 
            require: ['zurb-foundation']
            apply_to: ".(scss|sass)$"
```

Then I have imported in a base SCSS file `@import "foundation";` but when I run : `php app/console assetic:dump` I have the following error :

```
[Assetic\Exception\FilterException]                                                                                           
  An error occurred while running:                                                                                              
  '/usr/bin/ruby' '/usr/bin/compass' 'compile' '/tmp' '--images-dir' '/srv/www/vhosts/proj/app/../src/pro/MainB  
  undle/Resources/public/images' '--config' '/tmp/assetic_compass0NW1Qc' '--sass-dir' '' '--css-dir' '' '/tmp/assetic_compassT  
  0AFvM.scss'                                                                                                                   
  Error Output:                                                                                                                 

  Output:                                                                                                                       
     create web/sprites/flags-s566f9ef717.png                                                                                   
     create web/sprites/flags-s566f9ef717.png                                                                                   
      error assetic_compassT0AFvM.scss (Line 7: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation.                             
  Load paths:                                                                                                                   
    /tmp                                                                                                                        
    /usr/share/compass/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets                                                                         
    /usr/share/compass/frameworks/compass/stylesheets                                                                           
    /srv/www/vhosts/proj/src/pro/MainBundle/Resources/public/css                                                 
    /srv/www/vhosts/proj/src/pro/CompanyBundle/Resources/public/css                                              
    /srv/www/vhosts/proj/web/bundles/pro/css                                                                 
    Compass::SpriteImporter)                                                                                                    
     create assetic_compassT0AFvM.css                                                                                           
  Input:                                                                                                                        
  @import "base";                                                                                                               
  @import "header";                                                                                                             
  @import "global";                                                                                                             
  @import "foundation";
```

I saw also the upgrading page http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/upgrading.html where they say to change :

```
require "zurb-foundation"
```

to:

```
add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"
```

However is not working, do you have any suggestions of how to configure this in order to work properly?

---

**Change in configuration**

If I change in `config.yml` instead of *require* I use *plugins* :

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        compass: 
            plugins: ['zurb-foundation']
            apply_to: ".(scss|sass)$"
```

I get this error :

```
  [Assetic\Exception\FilterException]                                                                                           
  An error occurred while running:                                                                                              
  '/usr/bin/ruby' '/usr/bin/compass' 'compile' '/tmp' '--images-dir' '/srv/www/vhosts/proj/app/../src/pro/MainB  
  undle/Resources/public/images' '--config' '/tmp/assetic_compass0qewOn' '--sass-dir' '' '--css-dir' '' '/tmp/assetic_compassQ  
  uKtrw.scss'                                                                                                                   
  Error Output:                                                                                                                 
  LoadError on line ["36"] of /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb: cannot load such file -- zurb-foundation          
  Run with --trace to see the full backtrace                                                                                    
  Input:                                                                                                                        
  @import "base";                                                                                                               
  @import "header";                                                                                                             
  @import "global";                                                                                                             
  @import "foundation";
```

Comment: You do realize you're reading documentation for upgrading foundation in **Ruby on Rails**, not Symfony?

Comment: In http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/upgrading.html, there is a paragraph `Upgrade manually with Compass` and at stept 3 they say : `TELL COMPASS WHERE FOUNDATION RESIDES` I think there should be a connection because Symfony2 use Compass and this is what I want to config.

Comment: Section you are reading mentions `config.rb` files (which is Ruby file extension) and `require "zurb-foundation"` and `add_import_path "..."` are absolutely valid ruby syntaxes.

Comment: Compass need `config.rb` file in order to be configured! Now I know that the configuration of Compass is managed by Assetic in Symfony2. So I just wander what configuration to put in `config.yml` in order to work properly with Foundation5.

Comment: I have found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20619652 but doing as is suggested I have the same error : `File to import not found or unreadable: foundation.`

Comment: My starting point on this configuration was http://nerdpress.org/2012/10/26/symfony-2assetic-sass-compassfilter-foundation-responsive-front-end-framework/ but this article is form 2012 and is for Foundation4 and it seams that for Foundation5 is not the same as for Foundation4.

Comment: Is foundation in your $path? What does `which foundation` on the shell say?

Comment: `$ which foundation
/usr/local/bin/foundation
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have fond correct configuration in `config.yml` :

```
# Assetic Configuration assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        compass: 
            load_paths:
                 - '%kernel.root_dir%/../app/Resources/public/vendor/bower_components/foundation/scss'
            apply_to: ".(scss|sass)$"
```