# How to use the official zurb foundation bundle for symfony2?

Tags: symfony, zurb-foundation

my question may seems really pointless or I may look like an idiot, but I'd like to use Zurb Foundation in Symfony2.
I saw a little number of topics about it, but never an real a clear explanation on how to integrate it properly in my project.

I saw an official bundle on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/zurb/foundation). I installed it so. But there is no documentation for using it with symfony2. For example, how to call my css and js files ? From the vendor folder directly ? How to use compass in my symfony project to use it ? Should I use bower directly ? (this seems to me less painfull) And if yes, if I have an already existing Symfony2 project, may I use bower in the root of my project ? in web folder ? anywhere else ?

I'm really lost and would be greatfull if someone could explain me or give me some resources to help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For my website I put all my JS/CSS files in vendor *NameVendor*

In my layout

```
{% javascripts 
  'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js'
  '@NameBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}

{% stylesheets 
  '@NameBundle/Resources/public/css/*'
  filter='cssrewrite' output='css/*.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

In script tag

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).foundation();
});
```

In **App/config/config.yml**

```
 # Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ NameBundle ]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

I failed to use grunt to update my files so do it manually

Comment: ok so I uses the path `/home/me/www/project/vendor/zurb` directly. And what about compass ? Do I use it as usual, asking him to watch for my scss files or is there a better way to do that through Symfony ? I saw this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075824/foundation5-with-compass-and-assetic-in-symfony2 It seems to be an a parameter to use in config.yml. But the documentation from zurb doesn't seem to mention it actually, is it ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't use SASS

Comment: And this foundation [doc](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html) doesn't help you ?

Comment: Actually no as it doesnt give any instructions for symfony

Comment: And this [symfony post](http://alexandre-salome.fr/blog/Sass-Compass-Assetic-In-Ten-Minutes) ?

Comment: I saw this one. But two things (I may be wrong) : It only deals with sass and compass, not foundation. And also, the post's age -> July 31, 2011.
At the moment I'm trying another approach, without the official zurb foundation bundle, but bmatzner/BmatznerFoundationBundle. But your post may be usefull right now as the named bundle doesn't handle sass.

Comment: Also after this in order to work you need to run the following commands

php app/console cache:clear

php app/console assets:install --symlink

php app/console assetic:dump

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/florianbelhomme/FlobFoundationBundle

I think that's what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try and tell you what.

Comment: The Bundle is discontinued- use https://packagist.org/packages/zurb/foundation instead.